# How to solve rxjs Typescript error (Ionic 3, angularfire2)

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3, rxjs

I have reappearing errors when I try to serve my ionic 3 application using angularfire2.

These are the errors:

> Typescript Error ';' expected.
>   C:/Users/Admin/Verein/node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts
>
> export declare type ObservedValueOf = O extends
>   ObservableInput ? T : never;
>
> Typescript Error Expression expected.
>   C:/Users/Admin/Verein/node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts
>
> export declare type ObservedValueOf = O extends
>   ObservableInput ? T : never;
>
> Typescript Error 'ObservableInput' only refers to a type, but is being
>   used as a value here.
>   C:/Users/Admin/Verein/node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts
>
> Typescript Error Cannot find name 'infer'.
>   C:/Users/Admin/Verein/node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts

and many more all relating to rxjs. I am using it for example like this:

```
import { Note } from '../../model/note/note.model';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-aufgaben',
  templateUrl: 'aufgaben.html'
})
export class AufgabenPage {


  aufgaben: Observable<Note[]>;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private modal: ModalController, public events: Events, private db: AngularFireDatabase) {

      this.aufgaben = this.db.list('/aufgabenverzeichnis/').snapshotChanges().pipe(
     map(changes =>
       changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }))
     )
   );
  }
```

this is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "Verein",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.11",
    "@ionic-native/core": "~4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "~4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "~4.18.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.2.0",
    "@reactivex/rxjs": "^5.5.3",
    "angularfire2": "^5.1.1",
    "firebase": "^5.8.4",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.3",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "promise-polyfill": "^8.1.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.4.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.4.0",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.1",
    "@ionic/lab": "1.0.20",
    "typescript": "^2.6.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

I know it has something to do with the different versions but I read that installing rxjs compat should solve the problem. Problem is it never did. When I save parts of my project without changing anything in my IDE it works again after the lab page reloads, which is even weirder. So I really don't know what to do anymore. Please help.

**EDIT: After following the advise below and upgrading to typscript 2.7.2 and rxjs/rxjs-compat to 6.3.3 the errors above disappered but I am getting a bunch of new once which too disappear after randomly saving the project in my IDE but come back again if I ionic serve --lab anew. These are the new errors:**

I managed to get rid of a few of them (they were all syntax related) but there is one Type I can't get rid of because I don't know how to change the syntax. All erros left are like this:

Typescript Error
Type 'Observable<{ key: string; }[]>' is not assignable to type Observable<(Note[])>. Type '{ key: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'Note[]'. Type '{ key: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Note'. Property 'titel' is missing in type '{ key: string; }'.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ModalController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Note } from '../../model/note/note.model';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-aufgaben',
  templateUrl: 'aufgaben.html'
})
export class AufgabenPage {

  public color: string = 'primary';
  public color2: string ='primary';
  aufgaben: Observable<Note[]>;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private modal: ModalController, public events: Events, private db: AngularFireDatabase) {

/*error points to this.aufgaben*/ this.aufgaben = this.db.list('/aufgabenverzeichnis/').snapshotChanges().pipe(
         map(changes =>
           changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }))
         )
       );
      }
```

Note.model.ts:

```
 export interface Note {
  titel: string;
  beschreibung: string;
}
```

This error occurs multiple times in different ts files so I only listed one example. All of them disappear after saving and reappear after opening the app anew without me making any changes. So I really don't know how to fix this. Are those syntax errors related to the new typscript version?

**EDIT: I was able to resolve the issue by changing "`aufgaben: Observable<Note[]>`" to "`aufgaben: Observable<any[]>`.** Thanks for the help :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These issues are related with `rxjs` and `Typescript`. With `rxjs` new version(6.4.0), the minimum supported version of `TypeScript` is 2.8. But in your case `TypeScript` version is 2.6.2. That is the reason for this issue. To solve this issue, **upgrade `TypeScript` to 2.8 or downgrade `rxjs` and `rxjs-compat` to miner version which compatible with Typescript 2.6.2.**

In my case I downgraded `rxjs` and `rxjs-compat` to **6.3.3** version(My Typescript version was 2.7.2).

**[Find more information here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/4405)**

Comment: Thanks you for your advise. After changing rxjs to 6.3.3 and typescript to 2.7.2 the errors above disappeared but I am getting a bunch of new errors not related to rxjs anymore but to typescript and my code. Could it be because some of the synthax changed between the typescript version? I am pretty new to this so I don't really know what to make of it. Again those errors randomly disappeared after saving the projekt again without any changes but appear again when I serve the projekt again.

Comment: Edit: I was able to resolve the errors which occured after your advise so your answer definitely solved my problem :). Thanks for your advise.